# filter model according to DateField and TimeField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an Event model like following;

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    start = models.TimeField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='event_creator')
    info = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(EventUser, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is my serializer

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserListingField(many=True, read_only=True)
    creator = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='username')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
```

But I want to get only the events that is not outdated instead of all the events. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you using this event serializer? I assume in a DRF List View?

Comment: @AKS I think I have to change the queryset isn't it? instead of Event.object.all() , I have to use Event.objects.filter() something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the serializer in a [DRF Generic View](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes), you can either set the `queryset` attribute or use `get_queryset` method:

```
class MyListView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(<your filter conditions>)
```

Or, use the `get_queryset` method:

```
class MyListView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = EventSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(<your filter conditions>)
        return queryset
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know, I have to change the queryset but how can write the condition that compare datefield with current date?